# Chart with categories and sub-categories in x-axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Is it possible to have an x-axis with subgroups?

For example, I need to graph Categories: Greeting (1.1, 1.2, 1.3), Call Reason (2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4), Conclusion (3.1, 3.2, 3.3) , Accuracy (4.1, 4.2, 4.3)... etc.

The "1.1" numbers are the questions in the category and each question has a score ranging from 0% to 100%..

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve it with a pivot chart: insert a pivot chart, then select group and sub-group columns for axis labels and scores for values.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer a solution without a Pivot Table (or even better, without a Pivot Chart), you just need to modify your Horizontal Axis labels.  So, you'll need to:

1. Build your data set and insert a chart.
2. Right-Click your chart and choose Select Data.
3. In the Select Data Source dialog box, on the left side, choose your Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels and choose both columns that you want included in your Group/Subgroup, then select OK.
4. Format to taste.

Here's a sample:

[image]